# Laravel 5 Function name must be a string Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i suddenly got this error message 'Function name must be a string' when i try to read all of my model rows from database.

This is the code, i run when i get the error.

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return Customer::all();
}
```

This is the image of the error.

[image]

I don't understand what i could do so i can't run simple query to list all rows from database. Can anyone help me how to fix this ? I have checked all other posts from stackoverflow for this title but i could not find solution.

Comment: Clear config cache or update composer

Comment: @GAURAVVAGHELA i will give it a try

Comment: Have you defined any events on your customer model?

Comment: @GAURAVVAGHELA did not help

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: @Jason i have CustomerObserver which has only implemented update method, is it error in there ?

Comment: @Gudgip Version:  5.6.38

Comment: @JustCarty not duplicate, i gave it a look and did not help me. It is different case

Comment: Go to the Dispatcher file in vendor and `dd($payload);` Then let us know what's there

Comment: Hmm, looks like the listener you're adding is not a string (null?)? I think the error is in the calling method.

Comment: @Gudgip  Thank you ! I made mistake in AppServiceProvider. I have used 
Customer::observe(Customer::class); in observer instead of
Customer::observe(CustomerObserver::class);

Comment: @JustCarty I found the bug in my code. It was in AppServiceProvider. Thanks for help though...

Answer (score 7):

The problem was because i had CustomerObserver class and in AppServiceProvider i used wrong class

```
public function boot()
{
    Subscription::observe(SubscriptionObserver::class);
    SocialMediaAccount::observe(SocialMediaAccountObserver::class);
    Customer::observe(Customer::class);
}
```

I should use:

```
Customer::observe(CustomerObserver::class);
```

That caused my problem.